# Cheapest windows alternative to mainstage with sound effects

Tags: sound-effects, software

I am doing a musical for school, in which I will be playing on a keyboard, which will be connected by a MIDI-USB to my laptop, which will then apply a range of sound effects (synthesisers, electric pianos, organs, etc.) and put it out to an amp. What program would suit me best?